# Product And Category Separation In Route (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm setting up a new route system.

```
Route::get('/{cat1Url}', 'CategoryController@showCat1')->name('showCat1');

Route::get('/{productUrl}', 'ProductController@showProduct')->name('showProduct');
```

My sef link is after "/"
But,

```
{{ route('showProduct',[$p->pr_url]) }}
```

This method not working with route name. Working only upside route.

I don't want use 
"/cat/myVariable" 
or 
"/product/myVariable"

Can't I use route name to work this way?
What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In this way, if you make a get request to `/something` the laravel you start from top of web.php file looking to a route that follows the pattern. Your both routes will follow that pattern, but the laravel will always, pass the first one to controller.
You have two options:

1. Put only one route, and inside the controller you switch to the appropriate function. But this isn't a great ideia, because **this is the function of the Web.php**.
2. Use the routes like the documentation recommend:

```php
Route::get('/cat/{catId}', 'CategoryController@showCat')->name('showCat');

Route::get('/prod/{productId}', 'ProductController@showProduct')->name('showProduct');
```

and in Controller you make the appropriate handler of your Category or Product.

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't want use "/cat/myVariable" or "/product/myVariable"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have a way to tell Laravel which url to be mapped to what otherwise it will always use the last defined route. So in your case calling `/myVariable` and `/myVariable` it will use the latest definition which is `showProduct`. The only other way is if you use regular expression to differentiate the variables. For example:

```
Route::get('/{cat1Url}', 'CategoryController@showCat1')
    ->name('showCat1')->where('cat1Url', 'cat-*');

Route::get('/{productUrl}', 'ProductController@showProduct')
    ->name('showProduct')->where('productUrl', 'prod-*');
```

This way your slugs need to start with what you define, but you cannot use just `id` as a numeric value for both.